# setting the value of a checkbox programmatically in c# (wpf)

Tags: c#

I'm working on a small wpf project using c#.  I have 2 windows.  When I go from one window to the next, i need to have some items preselected on the 2nd window.  I have a checkbox that I need to set the value based on information that I pull from the registry.  On the 1st window, i have a reference to the 2nd window.  How can I set the checkbox to checked so that when the other window opens it's already checked?

```
 private void btnGoToNextWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            Window2 w2 = new Window2();

            //This doesn't work             
            w2.Checked = true;

            w2.Show();
            this.Close();
     }
```

Answer (score 20):

Using this:

```
        Window2 w2 = new Window2();

        //This doesn't work             
        w2.Checked = true;
```

You're setting the Checked property of the *window* not the *control*.  It should be somehting like this:

```
        Window2 w2 = new Window2();        
        w2.MyCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
```

Comment: There is no Checked property in WPF for the Checkbox

Comment: There is no Checked property in WPF please update your answer

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked%28VS.85%29.aspx) property.

I hope this helps.
Damian

Comment: Please, when an answer is useful mark it as answered. This way, other people can easily recognized it and the person who answered your questions gets credit for it.

Comment: this is way better answer, you should never use code behind. it's almost like hardcoding.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that you should move towards pushing the view model into the view via IoC or some other fashion. Tie the value to a property and let the framework make your life easier via binding, instead of having to hard code values all over the place.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: Misconception.  Having a variable in a view model, which gets set to a value, then gets retrieved (even through a binding) still "hard codes" it to a value, just through an elaborate maze of getters-setters.  That variable still has to get set originally from somewhere - even if from another property's value.  Why not set it directly to the box instead of through an over-bloated method of setting/retrieving the value to/from a model variable?  DataBinding for something this simple really is over-the-top.